# Re-render fullCalendar upon URL change in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar

This seems like it would be easy, however my fullCalendar is in it's own template, therefore I can't access the calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar() method from anywhere useful.

So to be more specific, how would I access all of the calendar.js information from other sources/templates?

Here is my re-render function

```
if(calendar) {
    calendar.refetchEvents();

    //Changes background color of days with events
    $('.fc-day').removeClass('has-event');
    var eventList = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for (var i = 0; i < eventList.length; i++){
        var date = eventList[i]._start;
        var formattedDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        $('[data-date="' + formattedDate + '"]').addClass('has-event');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the dayRender method of fullCalendar. It automatically loops through and rendered each calendar day every time the calendar changes, therefore you can make a simple logic render change as follows:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    var collectionValue = collection.find({key: value});
    for (var i = 0; i < collectionValue.length; i++) {
        if (date == collectionValue.value) {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to customize render of each individual day anytime anything changes.